# How to get JSON through ajax call from angularJS controller to MVC5 controller

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs

I am new with AngularJS. I want to make ajax call from my angular controller to my MVC5 controller. My **action** with **three parameters** resides in **HomeController** like

```
public ActionResult addFrnd(int name, string phone, int age)
    {
       //do something
        return json();
    }
```

and my angular controller goes here

```
var myModule = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);
myModule.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope, $http, SimpleFactory) {
        $scope.friends = [];
        init();


        function init() {
            $scope.friends = SimpleFactory.getFriend();
        }

        $scope.addFriend = function ($http) {
            $scope.friends.push(
                {
                    name: $scope.newFriend.name,
                    phone: $scope.newFriend.phone,
                    age: $scope.newFriend.age
                });
            //$http("/Home/addFrnd");

            $http.get({
                type: "POST",
                url: "~/Home/addFrnd",
                data: {
                    name: $scope.newFriend.name,
                    phone: $scope.newFriend.phone,
                    age: $scope.newFriend.age
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                }
            });
        };
    });
```

How can i fix this? Please help me

Comment: why are you passing the $http service to the addFriend function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of this may depend on your routing.  Either way you need to remove the "~" before home in your http call.  Another issue is that you are using $http.get and the type you specify is a post.  If it is in fact a post just use $http.post({  .   Also, specify in your mvc controller that this call is a post by using the post attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult addFrnd(int name, string phone, int age)
    {
       //do something
        return json();
    }
```

You can write your post in angular like this:

```
$scope.addFriend = function(){
addFriend()
.success(function(returnVal){
//success
})
.err(function(error){
//error
});
};

function addFriend(){
    var  data = {
                    name: $scope.newFriend.name,
                    phone: $scope.newFriend.phone,
                     age: $scope.newFriend.age
                    };

   return  $http.post('/Home/addFrnd/', data);
}
```

Also no need to pass $http into the scope function for $scope.addFriend, you have already injected it

Comment: Wow great. It works perfectly. Thanks for modifying the code and for providing valuable information

Comment: no problem.  If i were you i would read up on factories and modules.  They can come in handy for a data access layer for your controllers.  If you had this call to add friend in a factory, injected your factory and you could use it the same way.  then in another controller inject it and do the same without having to rewrite it.  Also helps if the url ever changes.